# iText7 remove stamp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7, stamp

First, I add a stamp to pdf files used iText7, about drawing's rev date... I get it.
Second, if I update the drawings, need to update the stamp information, the simplest, to delete the stamp and add it again. But, I can't get the stamps in pdf.

```cs
PdfArray stamps = page.GetPdfObject().GetAsArray(PdfName.Stamp);
```

I find this way to get stamps, but the stamp is null. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you add those stamps?

Comment: PdfStampAnnotation stampAnno = new PdfStampAnnotation(stampRect)
                        .SetStampName(new PdfName("StampRML"));                   
                    PdfFormXObject stampObj = tempDoc.GetFirstPage().CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
                    stampAnno.SetNormalAppearance(stampObj.GetPdfObject());
                    stampAnno.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
                    page.AddAnnotation(stampAnno);

Comment: Does my proposal work for you?

Comment: Yes, I have succeeded, Thanks

Comment: Great! In that case it would be nice to mark my answer as accepted (by clicking the check mark at its upper left, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/460854)).

Comment: ok，it‘s my first to used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a comment you added the stamps in question like this:

```c#
PdfStampAnnotation stampAnno = new PdfStampAnnotation(stampRect).SetStampName(new PdfName("StampRML"));
PdfFormXObject stampObj = tempDoc.GetFirstPage().CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
stampAnno.SetNormalAppearance(stampObj.GetPdfObject());
stampAnno.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
page.AddAnnotation(stampAnno);
```

I.e. as a stamp annotation with stamp name **StampRML**.

Thus, to remove it again, simply remove all annotations with that stamp name, e.g. like this:

```c#
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SOURCE_WITH_STAMP))
using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(RESULT_WITHOUT_STAMP))
using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter))
{
    for (int pageNr = 1; pageNr <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); pageNr++)
    {
        PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNr);
        IList<PdfAnnotation> annotations = page.GetAnnotations();
        for (int i = annotations.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            PdfAnnotation annotation = annotations[i];
            if (annotation is PdfStampAnnotation stamp)
            {
                if ("/StampRML" == stamp.GetStampName()?.ToString())
                {
                    page.RemoveAnnotation(stamp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*([RemoveStampAnnotation](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/csharp/annotate/RemoveStampAnnotation.cs#L22) test `testRemoveStampByShen`)*